# Non-primitive recursive functions

Tags: recursion, ackermann-function

For my school project i have chosen to do analyze Ackermann function as well as other functions that are recursive but not primitively recursive. I cannot seem to find good material on this, what i find is usually a ton of theory describing what those functions should look like. Where can i find more info on this topic? I would also like to see multiple proofs that Acermann function is not primitively recursive.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you very much, that answers my question about Ackermann function but i am still having trouble finding other examples of these kinds of functions.

Comment: You can find a few more examples on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Limitations).